# firebase command is not working after using yarn global on windows10

Tags: reactjs, firebase, yarnpkg, firebase-tools

I am installing firebase-tools with yarn with the following command:

```
yarn global add firebase-tools
```

After it I am trying:

```
firebase login
```

And It giving me command not found an error. Please answer to solve this problem.

I am using Windows 10 operating systems.

/// Also I have tried some methods described on StackOverflow but nothing works.
I need a reliable solution.

Answer (score 7):

If you installing firebase-tools using this command :

```
yarn global add firebase-tools
```

After that execute this command :

```
export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"
```

and then run the command `firebase login`

Answer (score 3):

1. First, you need to check if the `firebase-tools` package is installed, using `yarn info firebase-tools`.
2. Then, to log in, use `yarn firebase login`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble getting `firebase-tools` to work through Node.js, I recommend installing the pre-built binary for your platform. The standalone binary for windows can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-windows).

Comment: I have used that suggestion from firebase. It did'nt work.

Comment: I figure out that I only want to use command line tools, so I installed it with npm package manager.

```npm install -g firebase-tools ```

It is working fine now. I hope it did'nt make any problem with yarn later.